# Proving something is an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Let $A$ be an affine space associated to a vector space $V$ over a field $k$ (i.e. $V$ acts as an additive group on the set $A$ and this action is free and transitive). I want to prove that if a nonempty subset $S$ of $A$ contains all points of the form $p+\lambda \vec{pq}\in S$ for all $p,q\in S$ and $\lambda\in k$, then $S$ is an affine subspace of $A$ (i.e., $S=p+W$ for some $p\in A$ and some vector subspace $W$ of $V$).

My idea was to put $$W=\{\vec{qq'}|q,q'\in S\}$$ and prove that $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$, but i'm stuck on proving that it is closed under addition.

Comment: Hint: you need to assume that $S$ is nonempty. For $p\in S$, argue that $W=S-p$ is a vector subspace of $V$.

Comment: @blargoner Sorry, I thought it was obvious in my cuestion. I just edited it, $S$ is a non-empty set. Also I meant $W$ containing $0$ instead of $S$.

Comment: No worries. For addition, for $p,s_1,s_2\in S$, if $\vec{v_1}=s_1-p$ and $\vec{v_2}=s_2-p$, note that $q=s_1+\frac{1}{2}(s_2-s_1)\in S$, so $r=p+2(q-p)\in S$. Argue that $\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2}=r-p$. I'm assuming $k$ is of characteristic $\ne 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our hypothesis about the subset $S\subset A$ is
$$\forall p,q\in S\quad(pq)\subset S,$$
and we want to derive that
$$\forall a,b,c,d\in S\quad\exists p,q\in S\quad\overrightarrow{ab}+\overrightarrow{cd}=\overrightarrow{pq}.$$

We shall assume that the characteristic is $\ne2$ (when $k=\Bbb Z_2,$ the hypothesis is satisfied by *every* $S\subset A$).

We shall prove that we can even choose $p=a,$ i.e. that
$$q:=a+\overrightarrow{ab}+\overrightarrow{cd}=b+\overrightarrow{cd}\in S.$$

Let
$$r:=b+\frac12\overrightarrow{bd}\in S.$$ Then,
$$b+\overrightarrow{cd}=c+\overrightarrow{cb}+\overrightarrow{cd}=c+2\overrightarrow{cr}\in S.$$